# How to consume message from the endpoint in Apache Camel?

Tags: apache, apache-camel

I had created a message with a topic name and set some information with key/value pair and sent the message to the MessageBus (i.e, produced the message to an endPoint - in my case endpoint is a messageBus).

How can consume the message from that endPoint? I know the uri, endpoint. what configurations needs to be done for my consumer ( any camel XML changes to done ?).

Please help.

Comment: Sign is removed, Please refer the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Comment: Can you post your existing route definitions?

Comment: my route definition is test-proxy -> text-bus. the message is arrived on text-bus which is a activeMq. I need to write a consumer to read this message from the activeMq (which is the endpoint).

Comment: I suggest to read the Camel documentation a bit more before asking questions here. You questions is very broad and you do not provide much details what message bus you are using etc. For example read this tutorial: http://camel.apache.org/tutorial-jmsremoting.html. Then check the camel AMQ page: http://camel.apache.org/activemq.

Answer (score 0):

see the [camel-jms](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html) page for details, but you basically need to do some basic Spring XML to configure the ActiveMQ connection and then establish your route...

```
from("activemq:queue:inboundQueue").bean(MyConsumerBean.class);

<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
        <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
            <property name="brokerURL" value="vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false&broker.useJmx=false"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

see these unit test for more information...

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/components/camel-jms/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/jms/JmsRouteTest.java

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/components/camel-jms/src/test/resources/org/apache/camel/component/jms/jmsRouteUsingSpring.xml